# TaskCanceledException not being caught when using httpclient with polly policy

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I have a .net 6 console app that I configured with polly policies depending on what each service does.

Program.cs

```
try
{
  //other setup code

  services
   .AddHttpClient<ISubjectData, SubjectData>()
   .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(ConfigurePolicy);
   
  //other setup code

    IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> ConfigurePolicy(PolicyBuilder<HttpResponseMessage> policy)
    {
        try
        {
            return policy.Or<TaskCanceledException>()
                         .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 5));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

The policy is working, however, the program is throwing an unhandled exception which is `TaskCanceledException` because the `HttpClient` timed out, which isn't being caught by either catch statements or the policy in `ConfigurePolicy`.

How can I catch this error, since it is crashing the app?

Also, is there a way to allow Polly to override HTTP client timeout depending on how long it takes to complete all retries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:
You can't catch the exception because you wrapped the policy definition with `try`- `catch`es.

---

In case of Polly the policy definition and its execution are separated.

1. You define a policy (or a combination of policies)
2. You are decorating some method(s) with the above policy
3. You are executing the decorated method explicitly or implicitly through the policy.

Whenever you register a typed/named `HttpClient` and decorate its methods with an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` then you are doing only the first two steps.

Whenever you call a method on the `HttpClient`, like `PostAsync` or `SendAsync` that's where the policy is being executed on your behalf / implicitly (via a special `DelegatingHandler`).

That's where you can catch the exceptions

- ones which is thrown either by the `HttpClient` (like `TaskCancelledException`, `HttpRequestException`, etc.)
- or those that are thrown by one of the policies (like `TimeOutRejectedException`, `BrokenCircuitException`, etc.)

---

**UPDATE #1**

> What is confusing to me, is why does a try-catch block that covers my entire Program.cs not catch the exception, but a try-catch block in the scope of the request does? Aren't exceptions propagated back to the original caller? (The original caller would be a method inside my Program.cs file)

#### Try catch inside the `ConfigurePolicy`

As I stated above, here you are building the policy, not executing it. So, the try-catch here can be used to detect and resolve misconfiguration.

#### Try catch inside Program

Yet again the `AddHttpClient` and `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy` are just builder methods. They are not executing any http request on your behalf. So, wrapping this code into try-catch can help you to spot misconfiguration.

Your try-catch is covering those exceptions which are thrown by the `Main` but not those which are thrown by different threads which are not in the `Main`.

Comment: Thanks, I added a try-catch block where the HTTP request is actually being called and caught the exception. What is confusing to me, is why does a try-catch block that covers my entire Program.cs not catch the exception, but a try-catch block in the scope of the request does. Aren't exceptions propagated back to the original caller? (The original caller would be a method inside my Program.cs file)

Comment: @user19187727 I've updated my answer, please check it. I hope it brings clarity.